# Struts 1 - problem in showing ActionMessages through a JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, struts

I am using `Struts 1.3.10`. I am trying to display `ActionMessage` and `ActionError` set by `Action` class through a `JSP` page.

The problem is that the `ActionError`s are displaying well but `ActionMessage`s are not displaying. When I debug the application, I found that the `messages (reference variable of ActionMessages)` contains messages. I also saved those messages through `saveMessages(request, messages)` method of `Action` class.

So, I think that the problem is in the `JSP` code through which I am trying to display those messages. The `JSP` code is as follows:

```
<logic:messagesPresent>
    <ul id="messsages">
        <html:messages id="msg" message="true">
            <li><bean:write name="msg"/> </li>
        </html:messages>
    </ul>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add attribute `message="true` to the`<logic>` tag. By default, the value of `message` attribute is `false`.

The `<logic>` tag should look like

```
<logic:messagesPresent message="true">
```

Comment: You've asked similar questions like this before and I've helped. Nice to see you've figured it out.